# Databricks FLOOR() function errors on Target Scale

Tags: databricks

In my instance of Databricks, I'm not able to add a 2nd argument (Target Scale) to the `FLOOR` function as described [here](https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/functions/floor.html). I can successfully use floor without the Target Scale.

```
select floor(3345.1) --> works and returns a value of 3345

select floor(3345.1, -2) --> should return a value of 3300, but it errors:
*Invalid number of arguments for function floor. Expected: 1; Found: 2*
```

The following Python command shows I'm using Databricks Runtime Version 10.4.

```
%python
import os
print("DATABRICKS_RUNTIME_VERSION:",os.environ.get('DATABRICKS_RUNTIME_VERSION',None))

*DATABRICKS_RUNTIME_VERSION: 10.4*
```

More specifically, the Databricks Runtime Version in the cluster configuration is:

```
10.4 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.2.1, Scala 2.12)
```

Has anyone else experienced this error with `floor` (or similar) function?

***UPDATE***

I'm using AWS Databricks. At any rate, I updated my Runtime to version 11.3 and it works. So, I would say this is a bug with version 10.4 because their documentation states 10.0 and higher should work. Or their documentation is simply wrong.

Comment: are you azure databricks

Comment: No, using AWS. I'll update the question. Also, it works on 11.3, so this seemingly a bug with 10.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question here as it appears the documentation is wrong, or, there's a bug with Runtime Version 10.4.

**Updating my Runtime Version to 11.3 resolved the issue**. Even though the documentation states the function should work on 10.0 and higher, that is seemingly not the case. While the Floor() function works in 10.4, it would seem that **10.4 does not recognize the [target scale] argument**.